# About the 'time stamps' error in ROS

Tags: ros, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,I am doing some work on ROS  navigation,just at the start，and I encountered some problems.When I roslaunch the *.launch,there are a lot of erros like this:`[ERROR] [1493084059.568174116]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1493084059.049999952 but the latest data is at time 1493084059.012892115, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]`.It seems that time differences exist during the program running.How can I fix this error or how can I set the time to be the same during the program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260151/about-the-%27time-stamps%27--error-in-ros/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
What launch files are you running? Are you using a simulator or a real robot? What simulator or robot? Is your computer's clock set accurately?

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-25**:
not a real robot,but a small car based on arduino and raspberry Pi.the name of the launch file is`hongrobot_configuration.launch`,this may be a launch to set the nodes.Can I upload this file?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-25**:
If you are using hardware, then you are using a real robot. Not all robots are made by Kuka! :)

Yes, upload the launch file and the rest of your source so we can check it for problems.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-25**:
Are you using running nodes on any computers other than the Raspberry Pi? If you are, then you need to make sure their clocks are synchronised.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-25**:
Let's put the file aside.Sorry to forget the details:I run nodes on the raspberrypi to manipulate the arduino to controll the little car and send data of laser_scanner  to a Vmware machine(Ubuntu 14.04,bridged to the physical machine) and generating maps with RVIZ.But these errors only happen on the

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-25**:
RaspberryPi's terminal and maps did exist on RVIZ,but not so correc、explicit.And the car can't be self-navigated.How can I sychronize the time of raspberrypi with the virtualmachine？I baidu and googled these things and doubt about the time.Should I change the codes or just run some commands in the

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-25**:
terminal?谢谢你的热心帮助。望回复。

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter

*ntp1.flashdance 193.11.166.20    2 u   32   64  377  396.120  -29.788
8.509

+ec2-34-198-99-1 192.53.103.108   2 u   42   64  277  278.546  -36.187
8.326

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
+61-216-153-104. 62.161.56.158    3 u   30   64  367  208.137   22.236
9.779

-61-216-153-106. 62.161.56.158    3 u   37   64  377  207.653   21.762
7.686

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
upon is raspberrypi

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter

61.161.155.29   202.118.1.46     2 u    6   64    1   43.822    7.451   0.000

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
darwin.kenyonra 127.67.113.92    2 u    5   64    1  195.455    1.015   0.000

dns1.synet.edu. 202.118.1.48     2 u    4   64    1   43.509    3.007   0.000

61-216-153-106. 211.22.103.157   3 u    4   64    1  205.772   57.655   0.000

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-27**:
golem.canonical 193.79.237.14    2 u    2   64    1  346.202   -9.797   0.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up both your Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu (running in VMWare) to use a time synchronisation service.

Ubuntu should be set up automatically, I think, but [here is the documentation so you can check](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html).

For the Raspberry Pi, it depends on which OS you have installed. Are you using Raspbian? [Chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) is often mentioned as being both easy to set up and reliable on wifi connections (the original Turtlebot instructions [explicitly discuss it](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Setup/ntp)).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-25**:
really thanks

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
Hi,It's me.I found some strange things.Shall I scnchronize the system time of raspberrypi(os:Raspbian:jessie) to the Ubuntu or synchronize the ubuntu systemtime to raspberrypi?Shortly,I mean which is the time server?I install chrony on Ubuntu and did these:`sudo nano /etc/chrony/chrony.conf`

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
add a line`server 192.168.0.104 minpoll 0 maxpoll 5 maxdelay .05` `192.168.0.104`is the IP address of th Pi.Then,I restarted the chrony and `ntpdate`,it showed`26 Apr 15:23:22 ntpdate[4922]: no servers can be used, exiting`.It seems that Pi isn't the server.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
or should I synchronize both of the two's time to the ntpserver:`cn.pool.ntp.org`?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
You can sync one to the other, but you will need to set up a server on one of them and that's more trouble than it's worth in your case. Sync both of them to the same external server, such as `ntp.ubuntu.com`.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Raspbian Jessie apparently also has NTP time sync working out of the box. Does your Raspberry Pi have Internet access?

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
yes,with Wifi to the Internet

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
Please post the output of `ntpq -p` on both computers.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
can I upload pictures?I didn't find some option to upload pics

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
my teacher,Can i have your e-mail?I think it may be convenient for me to contact with you.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
oh,It's my dinner time,I will come back as soon as I can.

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-26**:
PS:twitter or facebook is Ok,I can use VPN sometimes,my college's ethernet can access the facebook

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
We need to keep using this page so that other people who have the same problem can find the solution.

You should add the output of `ntp -q` to your original question.